# AWK - how to set regexp item quantity ? Like Java's {n} {n, m} {n,}

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to write a simple regexp for the date format `dd/MM/YYYY` and time `HH:mm:ss`.
Google always references `GAWK: Effective AWK Programming` where I can see:

> [:digit:] - Numeric characters. and {n} {n,} {n,m} as quantifiers

There are no examples (or I can't find them) in this book about digit + quantifiers in complex regexps.

My regexp looks like:

```
echo 24/06/2013 | awk ' $0 ~ /[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{4}/ { print "MATCHES!"}'
```

And it does not work, although the similar example:

```
echo 24/06/2013 | awk ' $0 ~ /[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+\/[[:digit:]]+/ { print "MATCHES!"}'
```

works fine! Can anybody prompt the solution?
I use Cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to escape `/`:

```
 echo 24/06/2013 | awk ' $0 ~ /[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{4}/ { print "MATCHES!"}'
```

EDIT:

Makes the regex more precise:

```
echo 24/06/2013 | awk ' $0 ~ /^[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{2}\/[[:digit:]]{4}$/ { print "MATCHES!"}'
```

Comment: sorry about \ - it has removed by text formatter but it's still NOT working

Comment: I use win7 with Cygwin. As as it is written at FAQ to recognize Cygwin version - I use uname and it shows me MINGW32_NT-6.1

Comment: In fact the first version would also match `224/06/2012`, so i altered the regex a bit.

Comment: It works after updating Cygwin. Thanks a lot by your notice about ^